# How to send and get back data from Kafka in a single API call

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to send and get back data from Kafka in a single API call (see diagram below).

[image]

Is this possible? I already know how to make the data go in one direction (e.g., Spark Streaming reads data using the Kafka consumer API). I also know how to sort of 'fake it' by doing two one-way  approaches (e.g., the web app is both a producer and consumer). However, when the web app makes an API call, I only want it to have to deal with its own record, not all of the records in the topic, so this seems like the wrong approach.

Other sub-optimal approaches I've thought of:

1. Save the Spark Streaming result in a database so that the web app can constantly poll the database until the result shows up. I'm worried that this could consume a lot of resources and delay response time.
2. Create short-lived / temporary consumers each time I call the Kafka producer. The temporary consumer would filter out all records except for the one it's looking for. When it finds the record it's looking for, the temporary consumer shuts down. I don't think this would work because the record the API caller cares about might go to a different partition, and so it would never be found.
3. Make a temporary topic for each of the web app's consumer API calls. I'm not sure if Kafka will complain about too many topics though.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

What I did is....

1. Create a synProducer who send the data with a key and creates a consumer for a topic that has the name as the key of the sent message.
2. Then a synConsumer handle the message and reply to a topic, where the consumer at step 1 is waiting.
3. Delete the temporary topic

The downside of this approach is that the issues are not deleted immediately .

Comment: This sounds similar to the third approach I outlined in my original question.  Wouldn't this overwhelm Zookeeper (the utility that keeps track of topics)?  With this approach it would seem that Kafka and Zookeeper are doing the same amount of work, whereas generally Zookeeper has only a small footprint.

Comment: Yes, that could overwhelm the server  because deleted topics will not disappear immediately from Kafka server ... I just post a new approach in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you the third one, but with 2 topics: 1 for the request and 1 for the response. This is an example:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;
import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

public class ConsumerGroupExample extends Thread {

    private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
    private final String topic;
    private ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it;
    private String mensaje="";

    public ConsumerGroupExample(Properties props, String a_topic) 
    { 
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(props));
        this.topic = a_topic;

        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, 1);
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

        KafkaStream stream = streams.get(0); 
        it = stream.iterator();
    }

    public void shutdown()
    {
        if (consumer != null) consumer.shutdown();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if (it.hasNext())
        {
            mensaje = new String(it.next().message());
        }
        System.out.println( mensaje );
    }

    public String getMensaje()
    {
        return this.mensaje;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        props.put("group.id", "Group");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "400");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("consumer.timeout.ms", "10000");

        ConsumerGroupExample example = new ConsumerGroupExample( props, "topicFoRResponse");

        props = new Properties();
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("request.required.acks", "1");
        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);


        example.start();
        try {

            Producer<String, String> colaParaEscritura;
            KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("topicForRequest", " message ");
            colaParaEscritura = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, String>(config);
            colaParaEscritura.send(data);
            System.out.println("enviado");
            colaParaEscritura.close();

            example.join();

            System.out.println( "final"+ example.getMensaje() );

        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {

        }
        example.shutdown();
    }

}
```